# Problems importing imblearn python package on Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, imblearn, smote, oversampling

I want to use SMOTE to resampling my dataset. When I'm on Google Colab  and I tried to import the package using:

```
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
```

I get the error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name '_check_X' from 'imblearn.utils._validation' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/imblearn/utils/_validation.py)
```

What can I do to fix this error? Thanks

Comment: Hi, I tried it just right now on a fresh Google Colab notebook and the import natively works for me. I think you should precise your question. Also, please test on a fresh notebook if you didn't yet

Comment: @Bichon: I tried it with new notebook and it works. But when I add other codes (example: from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB), some other codes don't work. After that, when I delete code "from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE" and restart runtime, all other codes work. I don't understand :(